# How to get Ldap user changed attributes instead of all user attributes

Tags: python, ldap, openldap

Is there anyway to get user changed attributes instead of all user attributes?

```
import ldap
l = ldap.initialize("ldap://localhost")
l.protocol_version = 3
l.bind_s("cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org", "admin")
r = l.search_ext("dc=example,dc=org", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=*)")
print("Result", l.result3(r))
```

Comment: No. You can only get their current values and information like last modified date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this issue, you need to get openldap internal fields by adding a `+` sign at the end of search query like so:

```
$ ldapsearch -h localhost -w 'admin' -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -b "DC=example,DC=org" +
```

And in python code it would like this:

```
r = l.search_ext("dc=example,dc=org", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "objectClass=*", ["+",], 0)
```

Then it returns internal fields which are important like `modifyTimestamp`.

Or if you want to get all internal fields and user attributes in one request, just add `'*' '+'` like this:

```
 r = l.search_ext("dc=example,dc=org", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "objectClass=*", ["*", "+"], 0)
```

If you want to get last changed user after a specific date, try to add `modifyTimestamp` on query like this:

```
$ ldapsearch -h localhost -w 'admin' -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -b "DC=example,DC=org" "modifyTimestamp>=20171012152507Z
```

To get more info about history, try to enable `overlay accesslog` in your ldap and use it:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -b cn=accesslog
```

Resources:

- Active directory `whenChanged` field: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680921(v=vs.85).aspx
- Open ldap `modifyTimestamp` field: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_usingldapsearchtoreturnoperationalattributes_t.html
- Internal attributs: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ldap/2009q3/002593.html

  - https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ldap/2009q3/002594.html
- Access log: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Access%20Logging
- How to check the login history of users on openldap: https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201505/msg00117.html

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.